# any possibility to deploy same .war file on tomcat and websphere?

Tags: java, rest, tomcat, jakarta-ee, websphere

I want to develop web application which can run on both tomcat and websphere servers. are there any possibility to do that

any possibility to  deploy same .war file on tomcat  and websphere

Comment: Sure it's possible, just use the servlet API's only.  Otherwise, you are comparing an application server to (essentially) a servlet engine.  You have to make up for that by adding libraries to your application that are unneeded in an application server.

Comment: this is a common usage pattern I see with companies that use WebSphere in production but devs want to use Tomcat for local dev. Have a look at OpenLiberty/WebSphere Liberty which is free/lightweight/opensource for dev environments but also supported in production by IBM/WebSphere

Comment: Although it is possible, I'd be very far from recommending that. Your war will contain many unnecessary libraries, which will generate possible conflicts in runtime on WebSphere. Just as Andy said, instead of Tomcat, if you need open source, completely free server use OpenLiberty in dev (WebSphere Liberty is free for dev also) and WebSphere Liberty in production. Development and packaging will be much easier, and your war will be much smaller, as both OpenLiberty and Websphere Liberty fully support Java EE, not like Tomcat which is just a web container.

Comment: is it possible to deploy same .war which is deployed in a tomcat to websphere Liberty server